# Why does it always return true?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logical-operators

Beginner question, sorry if it's not the right place to ask
Trying to learn how logic works in `JS`, can't figure this out

```
if (firstSymbol === "A" || "a" || "D" || "d") {
    if (secondSymbol === "z") {
        alert("It does!"); 
        break;
    }
}
```

I expect it to say "It does!" and break in case if the `firstSymbol` is A, a, D or d AND the `secondSymbol` is z , but for some reason it says "It does!" and breaks regardless of what the `firstSymbol` is and only checks if the `secondSymbol` is z.

Comment: You have to write it like `(firstSymbol === "A" || firstSymbol === "a" || firstSymbol === "D" || firstSymbol === "d")`.

Comment: Yes, "A" || "a" resolves to "A"

Comment: Ah, ok, now i understand. Huge thanks:)

Comment: Or, you can do: `["A","a","D","d"].includes(firstSymbol)`... Or... `["a","d"].includes(firstSymbol.toLowerCase())`... Or.... `["A","a","D","d"].indexOf(firstSymbol) > -1`

Answer (score 2):

Because you're checking whether `"a"` is true - it is always true:

```js
console.log(!!"a");
```

You should be using `includes` and AND `&&` in this case:

```js
const firstSymbol = "D";
const secondSymbol = "z";
if (["A", "a", "D", "d"].includes(firstSymbol) && secondSymbol == "z") {
  console.log("It does!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function matchSecondSymbol(firstSymbol, secondSymbol) {
  // By making FirstSymbol Uppercase, we can remove the other two conditions
  firstSymbol = firstSymbol.toUpperCase();
  if (['A', 'D'].includes(firstSymbol) && secondSymbol === "z") {
      console.log('it Does');
  }
  else {
      console.log('it does not');
  }
}

matchSecondSymbol('a', 'z');
matchSecondSymbol('z', 'z');
matchSecondSymbol('a', 'y');
```

Comment: `=== "A" || "D"` is always testing against `"A"`

Comment: `firstSymbol.toUpperCase() === "A" || "D"` are you **100% sure** this will work as expected? :D

Comment: @briosheje except for accented characters, `localeCompare` should be used if non unicode characters are expected.

Comment: @Dementic that's not my point. `firstSymbol.toUpperCase() === "A" || "D"` will always evaluate against "A" only. `("A" || "D")` won't fix it, it still will evaluate against "A" Only.

Comment: @briosheje my bad, i missed the parentheses

Comment: But ("A" || "D")  is a constant value of "A"

Comment: @Dementic take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/951ae4jk/, it may help you understand what me and Alex are saying.

Comment: Just use `.includes` instead as mentioned in other comments, or indexOf, or just evaluate every single value.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript there's something called [`truthy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values. In summary, is how a value evaluates in a Boolean (`true` or `false`) context.

> All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy (i.e., except for false, 0, "", null, undefined, and NaN).

In your code, when you wrote:

```
if (firstSymbol === "A" || "a" || "D" || "d")
```

You are checking 4 boolean conditions:

1. `firstSymbol === "A"` - The result will depend on `firstSymbol`
2. `"a"` - Will always evaluate to `true`
3. `"D"` - Will always evaluate to `true`
4. `"d"` - Will always evaluate to `true`

So, since conditions 2, 3 and 4 will always be `true`, your code will always enter the `if` statement. If even a single one of these would be `true` the behaviour would be the same.

You can rewrite it in some ways:

```
if (firstSymbol === "A" || firstSymbol === "a" || firstSymbol === "D" || firstSymbol === "d")
```

or

```
if (["A", "a", "D", "d"].indexOf(firstSymbol) > -1)
```

or

```
if (["A", "D"].indexOf(firstSymbol.toUpperCase()) > -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add something to the boilerplate, these are some examples to accomplish what you're trying to do, with tons of possibilities.

Tests covered:

- using `array.includes`
- using `array.indexOf`
- using `array.find`
- using `array.some`

**WHY didn't your code work?**

It didn't work because javascript evaluates the following expression: `"A" || "a" || "D" || "d"` to `"A"`, because "A" is **truthy**. If you need to compare with multiple values, either use an array, either write the condition for each of them:
`firstSymbol === "A" || firstSymbol === "D" ||...`

Examples mentioned above:

```js
/* Original code */
/*
if (firstSymbol === "A" || "a" || "D" || "d") {if (secondSymbol === "z") alert("It does!"); break;}
*/

let firstSymbol = "d", secondSymbol = "z";

// Using .includes
if (["A","a","D","d"].includes(firstSymbol) && secondSymbol === "z") console.log('it does, with .includes');

// Cleverer .includes due to the nature of the input.
if (["a","d"].includes(firstSymbol.toLowerCase()) && secondSymbol === "z") console.log('it does, with cleverer .includes');

// Using .indexOf
if (["A","a","D","d"].indexOf(firstSymbol) > -1 && secondSymbol === "z") console.log('it does, with .indexOf');

// Using .find
if (["A","a","D","d"].find(i => i === firstSymbol) && secondSymbol === "z") console.log('it does, with .find');

// Using. some
if (["A","a","D","d"].some(i => i === firstSymbol) && secondSymbol === "z") console.log('it does, with .some');
```

Answer (score 0):

## Order of Precedence decides

In each programming language, symbols are processed in order of their precedence order.

## In Short:

AS the others already explained, your assignment

```
firstSymbol === "A" || "a" || "D" || "d"
```

would be processed as

```
(firstSymbol === "A") || ("a") || ("D") || ("d")
```

Link to how logical operators are processed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence